# Relative Condition Number of Atan(x) vs Atan2(y,x)

Tags: numerical-methods, perturbation-theory, condition-number

I'm trying to think through the sensitivity of atan2 to errors in its inputs and I've run into a disconnect that I don't quite understand.

I know that you can compute the relative condition number of a differential function $f$ as:

$$\kappa(\vec{x}) = \frac{\Vert\mathbb{J}_f(\vec{x})\Vert}{\Vert f(\vec{x})\Vert/\Vert \vec{x}\Vert}$$

Where the norm on the Jacobian is the induced norm.

For $atan(x)$ you end up with simply the derivative $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ so it works out to: $$\kappa(x) = \frac{x}{(1+x^2)atan(x)}$$

Which is very nicely behaved:

[image]

If I look at it on the unit circle and compute K(y/x), it looks well behaved too:

[image]

However, looking at atan2(y,x) = atan(y/x), you end up with:

$$\mathbb{J}(y,x) = \{\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}, \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\}$$

It turns out the induced $L_2$ norm for this is 1, and in my particular case, my x and y values are indeed a sine and cosine pair so $\Vert <x,y>\Vert = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} = 1$

This leaves you with $\kappa(y,x) = \frac{1}{\vert atan2(y,x)\vert}$ which is less well behaved for positive x and y near zero:

[image]

I believe the math here but I'm struggling to interpret the results in a consistent way, since atan2 is fundamentally just atan with logic to interpret the sign correctly.

Why does atan2 seem to get very sensitive near zero and atan doesn't?

Edit: Made atan2 and related equations consistently (y,x) order.

Comment: The reason to be concerned about relative condition number is the idea that computing $f(x)=0.002$ when the correct value is $f(x)=0.001$ is much, much worse than computing $f(x)=99.002$ when the correct value is $f(x)=99.001$. In your application, is it really any worse to say $\operatorname{atan2}(y,x)=0.001$ instead of $\operatorname{atan2}(y,x)=0$ than it is to say $\operatorname{atan2}(y,x)=\frac\pi2+0.001$ instead of $\operatorname{atan2}(y,x)=\frac\pi2$?

Comment: $atan(y) = atan2(y,1)$, so $atan()$ stays away from from $(0,0)$, which is where $atan2()$ gets into trouble?

Comment: I think what it all comes down to is that as $y\to 0,$ $\|y\|\to 0$ (for atan) whereas $\|(x,y)\|=1$ (for atan$2$). So atan to gets a pass because at the point where its output has a huge percentage change, its input is perceived as having an equally huge percentage change. There are implicit assumptions in there about how the numbers are to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Condition number shows how **relative** perturbation of the argument(s) result in relative change in function value.

You show that atan is good conditioned, so any perturbation of $x$ cannot result in bigger relative perturbation of $\operatorname{atan} x$. I was suprised that for nonlinear functions $\kappa$ may be less than 1, for linear ones that is impossible.

Let's study how atan2 is sensitive to perturbation of $x$ and $y$ separately:
$$
\kappa_x(y, x) = \frac{|\operatorname{atan2}(y, x+\delta x)-\operatorname{atan2}(y, x)| / |\delta x|}{|\operatorname{atan2}(y, x)| / \|(x, y)\|} = \frac{|y|}{|\operatorname{atan2}(y, x)|}
$$
*Mathematica* defines atan2 with branch cut along $(-\infty, 0]$, so atan2 near $y = 0$, $x = 1$ behaves like $\operatorname{atan2}(y, x) \approx y$, so $\kappa_x \approx 1$.

Similarly
$$
\kappa_y(y, x) = \frac{|x|}{|\operatorname{atan2}(y, x)|}.
$$
Near $x = 1, y = 0$ we have $\kappa_y = |x/y| \to \infty$. There's no magic in this result. The relative perturbation of function is like $\delta y / y$, while relative perturbation of the argument is $\delta y/1$ (thanks to $x$). Sure thing $\delta y / y$ may be big, while $\delta y$ remain quite small.

The difference in $\operatorname{atan} \frac{y}{x}$ and $\operatorname{atan2}(y, x)$ the condition numbers essentially contain different $\|x\|$ in their definition, the former has $|y/x|$, while the latter has $\|(x, y)\| = 1$.

Comment: This makes sense to me I think.

Answer (score 5):

$$\operatorname{atan2}(y, x) = \arctan(\frac{y}{x}) + (\textit{quadrant fixup if } x < 0)$$

**You're dividing by x.  This is an ill-conditioned operation if x is near 0.**

To formalize things a bit, take the division $q = \frac{y}{x}$ and perturb it to $\tilde{q} = \frac{y + \Delta y}{x + \Delta x}$.

$$\tilde{q} = \frac{y + \Delta y}{x + \Delta x} \frac{x - \Delta x}{x - \Delta x}$$
$$= \frac{xy - y\Delta{x} + x\Delta y - \Delta x \Delta y}{x^2 - (\Delta x)^2}$$

Let's assume that the deltas are small enough that for all practical purposes, $(\Delta x)^2 = 0$ and $\Delta x \Delta y = 0$.  Then,

$$\tilde{q} \approx \frac{xy - y\Delta{x} + x\Delta y}{x^2}$$
$$= q - \frac{x\Delta y - y\Delta{x}}{x^2}$$
$$\text{error} = |q - \tilde{q}| \le \frac{1}{|x|}|\Delta y| + \frac{|y|}{x^2} |\Delta x|$$
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} |q - \tilde{q}| = \infty$$

Comment: Looking at the plot, the ill conditioning seems to be where x > 0 and y ~= 0 though, e.g. (1, 0) has a very poor condition number, and y/x is 0 at that point.  From your error calculation the error should be ~dy there. I understand I'm dividing by zero so I have a pole where y = 0, but I don't understand why its different from the places where tan(x) goes to zero.

Comment: Isn't your plot using relative rather than absolute error, though?

Comment: It's just a plot of the condition number itself for each

Comment: Further confused since division supposedly has a condition number of 1, which also doesn't make sense to me [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number#One_variable)